# Get json properties by attributes c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a Json Object like the one below.

```
"log": {
    "Response": [
      {
        "@type": "Authentication",
         "Status": "True",
        "Token": "cc622e9c-0d56-4774-8d79-543c525471b4"
},
{
        "@type": "GetApplication",
        "AppId": 100,
        "Available": "True"
}]}
```

I need to access the appId property. I have tried the below code which gives the null reference error. Please help me figure out the mistake.

```
 dynamic JsonText = JObject.Parse(result);
 string AppId= JsonText ["log"]["Response @type='GetApplication'"]["AppId"].Tostring();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g52Vm5)

```
          string json = @"{
    ""log"": {

        ""Response"": [{
            ""@type"": ""Authentication"",
            ""Status"": ""True"",
            ""Token"": ""cc622e9c-0d56-4774-8d79-543c525471b4""

        }, {
            ""@type"": ""GetApplication"",
            ""AppId"": 100,
            ""Available"": ""True""
        }]
    }
}";

            JObject result = JObject.Parse(json);

            foreach(var item in result["log"]["Response"])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item["@type"]);
                Console.WriteLine(item["AppId"]);
            }
```

You don't need to use dynamic, use `JObject` and after that loop in the Responses and take the `@type`

Comment: Thank u... Let me try this

Comment: @user3064309 you can mark the answer as correct if helped you.

Answer (score 4):

To to access the `AppId` property like the way you are showing in your example:

```
string AppId = JObject.Parse(result)["log"].SelectToken("$.Response[?(@.@type=='GetApplication')]")["AppId"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  http://json2csharp.com/ and generate model class, using  Newtonsoft.Json and LINQ get id as I show.

model class

```
public class Response
{   [JsonProperty("@type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("AppId")]
    public int? AppId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Available")]
    public string Available { get; set; }
}

public class Log
{
    public List<Response> Response { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Log log { get; set; }
}
```

.cs

```
   var  results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
   var id=    results.log.Response.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type == "GetApplication").AppId;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string json = @"{
    ""log"": {

        ""Response"": [{
            ""@type"": ""Authentication"",
            ""Status"": ""True"",
            ""Token"": ""cc622e9c-0d56-4774-8d79-543c525471b4""

        }, {
            ""@type"": ""GetApplication"",
            ""AppId"": 100,
            ""Available"": ""True""
        }]
    }
}";

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(result);
string AppId = obj["log"]["Response"][1]["AppId"].ToString();
Console.WriteLine(AppId);
```

@user3064309 hi, if `("@type": "GetApplication")` is the second and not change location. so you can use `obj["log"]["Response"][1]["AppId"].ToString()`;

Answer (score 0):

I have written an extension function that will be the third level of depth. You can make its depth as generic if you need, so the code below

```
public static object GetJsonPropValue(this object obj, params string[] props)
{
    try
    {
        var jsonString = obj.ToString().Replace("=", ":");
        var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
        foreach (var o in objects)
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Parse("{" + o.ToString().Replace("=", ":") + "}");

            if (props.Count() == 1 && jo.SelectToken(props[0]) != null)
                return jo.SelectToken(props[0]).ToString();

            if (props.Count() == 2 && jo.SelectToken(props[0])?.SelectToken(props[1]) != null)
                return jo.SelectToken(props[0])?.SelectToken(props[1]).ToString();

            if (props.Count() == 2 && jo.SelectToken(props[0])?.SelectToken(props[1])?.SelectToken(props[2]) != null)
                return jo.SelectToken(props[0])?.SelectToken(props[1])?.SelectToken(props[2]).ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("GetJsonPropValue : " + ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also i written an extension for normal c# objects, getting prop value dynamically

```
public static object GetPropValue(this object obj, Type typeName, string propName)
{
    try
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(typeName.GetProperties());

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.Name == propName)
            {
                object propValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
                return propValue;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("GetPropValue : " + ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```